# Trouble with excel macros (possibly encoding?)

Tags: excel, vba, encoding

We have in our office setted system in excel sheet, which we share and editing all together (6 computers) and one day from middle of nowhere, one of the computers starts to have troubles with macros. Macros which have in name letter with diacritics renamed, like if the encoding was changed but its just on one computer, others work fine. Also it added name of the file beffore the macro name. How to solve this? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest workaround way is to rename them and not use any odd characters besides english ones. Any other characters can cause issues depending on the region settings of the computer using it.

So if using different region settings on different computers: Do not use foreign characters in your VBA editor, or you can run into such issues.

To solve your issue:

- Replace your macro names with english ones to ensure they work in every region world wide
- or check your region settings and ensure every computer uses the same settings and same codepage

Also see [How To Display Foreign Characters In Excel VBE](https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)

Comment: After night trying to solve it, we bought newer version, reinstall it and starts to work again. Yeah, we not going to use diacritics anymore, just don't understand how this happened, just the name was showing bad, the code behind was showing right. Anyway, thanks for your effort.